# NSIS: find the target of a link

Tags: nsis, shortcut

Is there a way to check what is the target of a link, using NSIS ?

[ I want to check and update links on desktop, but I have a hard time checking if they belong to my application, because the name may contain a space or something, so it may not be identical...

I also want to delete links that are no longer used, that point to my folder.

So... I would like to look at the target, but can't fins anything that gives it to me. ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [ShellLink plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ShellLink_plug-in) or call the IShellLink+IPersistFile COM interfaces directly with the system plugin but normally a uninstaller/updater will only deal with shortcuts it created and not things the user might have created/renamed...